# Menu theming is not being applied as expected

Tags: routes

this is a bit of a backwards question, in that "not being applied as expected" means "I expected it to break, and it didn't". However, I'd like to know WHY I'm seeing the behaviour that I do.

I'm generating a path-specific site submenu, as [detailed in this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91077/how-to-fetch-submenu-items-for-current-page). Briefly, I'm rendering the main menu exactly how it is in the default page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix')))); ?>
```

... but the submenu is custom-built (see function in linked question) and rendered via:

```
print drupal_render($page_submenu);
```

I need to adjust the HTML output for my submenu, and have added the following to my theme's template.php:

```
function mytheme_menu_tree($variables){
  return '<ul class="your-custom-class" id="your-custom-id">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
function mytheme_menu_link($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . "</li>\n";
}
```

This does have the required effect on my submenu HTML output. However, it doesn't adjust anything in the main menu HTML output. Even though I don't want it to, I'd like to know why those two functions haven't affected it, because I was kinda expecting them to.